# Section headers in UICollectionView, only first one appears

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have created a class for a section header and am loading it into my UICollectionView. I am able to display the first header (albeit oddly, see below), however any following section headers are blank. The size is being referenced, the content (background color, label) won't appear though.

And then also...the one section header that does show, it is displayed with an indentation of approx. 150px for no apparent reason. Are headers center aligned by default? If so, how would I left align those?

My Section Header class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        let section = indexPath.section
        switch section {
        case 0:
            let tagsHeader = searchCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "TagsHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderView
            tagsHeader.headerString = "Recent Tags"
            tagsHeader.backgroundColor = .green
            return tagsHeader
        default:
            let tagsHeader = searchCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "TypeHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderView
            tagsHeader.headerString = "Type"
            tagsHeader.backgroundColor = .blue
            return tagsHeader
        }
    default:
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

In my UICollectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        let section = indexPath.section
        switch section {
        case 0:
            let tagsHeader = searchCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "TagsHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderView
            tagsHeader.headerString = "Recent Tags"
            tagsHeader.backgroundColor = .green
            return tagsHeader
        default:
            let tagsHeader = searchCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "TypesHeaderView", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderView
            tagsHeader.headerString = "Type"
            tagsHeader.backgroundColor = .blue
            return tagsHeader
        }
    default:
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    if section == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 18 + 22 + 6)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

This is how I instantiate my UICollectionView

```
let searchCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 6
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 6
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.isScrollEnabled = false
    cv.register(TokenCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TokenCell")
    cv.register(SectionHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "TagsHeaderView")
    cv.register(SectionHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "TypesHeaderView")
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv
}()
```

My CollectionViewFlowLayout

```
class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

    var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
    var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
    attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
        if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
            leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        }

        layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

        leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
        maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY , maxY)
    }

    return attributes
}
```

}

Here is a screenshot of the current result. You can see that the first header appears, however indented. The second header has its space, but none of its content appears. [image]

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting to switch section and not row? There's usually only one section that has multiple rows. The issue probably lies in the fact that you only have one section, so the default never gets called. Try changing anywhere you use the word "section" to "row"

Comment: Yes pretty sure I want section. I have two sections in my collectionView. The items are displaying and everything is working on that end. It's just the second header. I am also setting the referenceSizeForHeaderInSection which is working just fine.

Comment: You are right about the part that my default case isn't triggered though. Setting a breakpoint there, it is never reached. Trying to set that case to section == 1 isn't either. Is this not how I would reach my section or place individual headers per section?

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem when making my tag view.
The problem is in your `CollectionViewFlowLayout`.

`let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)`

This line is getting all the attributes including cells, supplementaryviews and decorationviews, which means you are changing attributes for header and footer too.

We can change the code to:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

    var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
    var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
    attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
        //check if the layoutAttribute is for cell
        if layoutAttribute.representedElementCategory == .cell {
                if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
                    leftMargin = sectionInset.left
                }

                layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

                leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
                maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY , maxY)
            }
    }

    return attributes
}
```

In order to apply the attribute to just cell. Then your header and footer will appear properly.